# convert date into day in year of a Dataframe in Python

Tags: python, date, datetime

I have a Dataframe traindf having Date column with the date in the format "YYYY-MM-DD". I am trying to convert the date in day in the year and append to the year. For ex. "2010-02-05" to "2010036". I got the below code working but want to check if there are any efficient way to get it.

dtstrip = [int('%d%03d' % (datetime.datetime.strptime(dt, fmt).timetuple().tm_year, datetime.datetime.strptime(dt, fmt).timetuple().tm_yday)) for dt in traindf['Date']]

traindf['Date'] = dtstrip

Comment: Requests to improve working code belong on codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this?

```
today = datetime.datetime.now()
print(today.strftime('%Y%j'))
```

For today the output is:

```
2017260
```